# How to map changes of .NET application from docker and rebuild?

Tags: docker, build, .net-core, publish

I am currently developing a `NET Application` and I have to run bash scripts that:

- 1.`Build` the project
- 2.`dotnet publish -c Release` the project
- 3.`copy` the `publish` folder to a path for `Dockerfile` to take on.

Can this be done directly from the `dockerfile`?

What I am running now:

**Bash-script**

```
dotnet build  ../${serverSrcFolder} &&
dotnet publish -c Release ../${serverSrcFolder} --output $(pwd)/${serverPublishDestFolder}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet" , "./publish/Server.dll" ]
EXPOSE 9400
EXPOSE 6379
```

The `publish` folder stays near the `dockerfile`.

- ParentFolder

  - Dockerfile
  - publish

The `serverPublishDestFolder` from the `bash` script above is this `publish` folder.

Can I somehow always map the `publish` folder whenever it changes from within the `dockerfile`?

Comment: Are you looking to update the publish folder in the docker image so that it references  the latest .dll and other artifacts?
The Dockerfile is the bill of materials passed to your docker daemon to build your docker image which is thus immutable. So if there is a change in code and a dotnet publish done then the image has to be rebuilt.

The other option (not recommended for production) is to mount the directory from the host into the running container from the above image.
i.e. docker run -v "$(pwd)/publish":/app/publish <yourdockerimage>
Not sure how hot redeployment of .net core works.

Comment: I want to perform the first option as you correctly stated. I want everytime i run the `dockerfile`,first to build and publish the `dll`,and using that path to inject it in the newly formed image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do three steps above inside the `Dockerfile`

e.g.

```
ROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.5-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.403-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/WebApi/WebApi.csproj src/WebApi/
RUN dotnet restore src/WebApi/WebApi.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/WebApi
RUN dotnet build WebApi.csproj -c Release -o /app 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebApi.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

This `Dockerfile` can be easily generated by [Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.2)